Finding probablities (to find the expected value) in a game of throwing a dice. where you win on getting 5 or 6 and losing otherwise, stopping on win
The question I saw was: In a game, a man wins 100 points if he gets 5 or 6 on a throw of a fair die and lose 50 points for getting any other number. If he decides to throw the die either till he gets a five or six or to a maximum of 3 throws, what is his expected gain/loss?
On the solutions provided to me, they made 4 cases of outcomes, which are: LLL, LLW, LW, W where L denotes getting any of 1,2,3 or 4 and W denotes getting 5 or 6. The cases respectively got -150, 0, +50 and +100 points. The probability of L was taken to be $\frac46$ and probability of W was taken as $\frac26$ which makes sense. Using a probability distribution table, they found the expected value by adding the products of the probability of each case and their respective points, which came out to be zero.




-150 points
0 points
+50 points
+100 points




Probablity
$(\frac{4}{6})^3$
$(\frac{4}{6})^2×(\frac{2}{6})$
$(\frac{4}{6})×(\frac{2}{6})$
$(\frac{2}{6})$



$Expected$ $value$ = $(-150)×(\frac{4}{6})^3$ + $(0)×(\frac{4}{6})^2(\frac{2}{6})$ + $(50)×(\frac{4}{6})(\frac{2}{6})$ + $(100)×(\frac{2}{6})$ $= 0$
My approach to the problem was slightly different and I'm unable to understand what I'm doing wrong. I made the same cases, i.e. LLL, LLW, LW and W.
LLL has 4×4×4 = 64 total outcomes (that look like: 1,1,1 and 1,2,4 and so on)
Similarly, LLW has 4×4×2 = 32 outcomes, LW has 4×2 = 8 outcomes and W has 2 outcomes. The sum of all the outcomes would be the total outcomes = 64+32+8+2=106
So, I thought that the probability of "LLL" happening was $\frac{64}{106}$, "LLW" happening was $\frac{32}{106}$, "LW" happening was $\frac8{106}$ and "W" happening was $\frac2{106}$. This is different from $(\frac{4}{6})^3$ and $(\frac{4}{6})^2(\frac{2}{6})$ etc. used in the actual solution. And therefore my answer isn't right. How?

"The sum of all the outcomes would be the total outcomes = 64+32+8+2=106" -- This is irrelevant to a solution unless you're claiming each outcome is equally likely.  They aren't.

@BrianMoehring I see! Is it because the outcomes of LW and W are just 2 and 1 throw of dice, which is completely different from the 3 throws of LLL and LLW and hence making them unequally likely?

Yes.  If you wanted them to be equally likely, you'd need to pretend each situation had three throws of the dice, giving something like WXX, LWX, LLW, LLL, where X denoted a throw that doesn't matter but would be used to justify applying your formula.  (if you decide to do this, you should have the total number of outcomes be $6^3 = 216$)

@BrianMoehring That made perfect sense! Thanks a lot! I clarified this by doing, 444 + 442 + 426 + 266 (respectively for LLL, LLW, LWX, WXX) which is 216.
